extract day/hour/minute/seconds are returning different values in oracle and snowflake
I have columns column1 and column2. When trying to extract day, hour, minute and seconds they are coming differently in Oracle and Snowflake.



column1
column2




2016-07-19 11:31:09.165
2016-07-18 14:00:51.110



In Oracle:
select extract(day from (column1 - column2)) from table;    -- returns 0 
select extract(hour from (column1 - column2)) from table;   -- returns 21
select extract(minute from (column1 - column2)) from table; -- returns 30
select extract(second from (column1 - column2)) from table; -- returns 17.889

In Snowflake, I used date diff but the values are very different.
The values as to match between oracle and snowflake. Can anyone help on this?

And the question is ...?

Please [edit] your post and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for both Oracle and Snowflake; the query you use in Snowflake; the output of the Snowflake query; and a question. Without the relevant code and setup details it is impossible to answer why there is a difference and without a question there is nothing to answer.

If you read the documentation for DATEDIFF, when you use a unit (like hours, minutes), it discards any part smaller than the unit you want:

Smaller units are not used, so values are not rounded.

In other words, when you run this:
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, column2, column1) AS diff_hours;

you might think you're comparing these two:



column1
column2




2016-07-19 11:31:09.165
2016-07-18 14:00:51.110



But it's actually comparing these:



column1
column2




2016-07-19 00:00:00.000
2016-07-18 00:00:00.000



So your answer will be 1 instead of 0.
You can use the same extract(day from (column1 - column2)) Oracle syntax in Snowflake, so I'm not sure why you're using DATEDIFF. If you need the output to match, use the same code.
Or - if you want Oracle to match the DATEDIFF behavior, do something like:
select extract(day from (trunc(column1,'DAY') - trunc(column2,'DAY'))) from table;
select extract(hour from (trunc(column1,'HOUR') - trunc(column2,'HOUR'))) from table;

